# deploy with maven on tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, maven, deployment

Hi i'm trying to deploy my application with maven. Over the web-interface deploying woks. but maven first undeploys th app (this is rght) and then stops for ca.30 secs at the logmessage "Uploaded" and fails:

tomcat7:deploy

```
[INFO] Deploying war to http://192.168.1.137:8080/Application
Uploading: http://192.168.1.137:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2FApplication&update=true
Uploaded: http://192.168.1.137:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2FApplication&update=true (17575 KB at 23215.6 KB/sec)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 57.061s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 06 09:41:27 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0-beta-1:deploy (default-cli) on project Application: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: The target server failed to respond -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

the config in my pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://192.168.1.137:8080/manager/html</url>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <path>/Application</path>
        <update>true</update>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

i also tried the old plugin with tomcat:redeploy:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://192.168.1.137:8080/manager/html</url>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <path>/Application</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but it fails too with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project Application: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Unexpected end of file from server -> [Help 1]
```

is it possible to change the timeout for deploying? maybe my app needs to long to start

EDIT:
i found out that when i checkout the project and run the tomcat7:deploy on the same machine where tomcat is running it works

Answer (score 3):

Though a late answer , someone might find this useful.
If you are using maven3 and tomcat7.The below method worked for me.I was not aware of the change in application manager endpoint in tomcat7.

```
Environment - Apache Maven 3.0.4,apache-tomcat-7.0.34,Windows 7
```

Tomcat7 has changed its deployment end point from `http://tomcatserver:8080/manager/html` to `http://tomcatserver:8080/manager/text`  .

So my pom.xml will be

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
           <url>http://tomcatserver:8080/manager/text</url>
           <server>tomcat</server>
          <path>/myWebApp</path>
         </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

In tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>

  <user username="root" password="root" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
```

In maven settings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>tomcat</id>
  <username>root</username>
  <password>root</password>
</server>
```

In context.xml , though this is optional and is not related to maven3 deployment to tomcat7 ,sometimes jar locking might happen,so to be on the safer side.

```
<Context  antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

Now issue

```
mvn tomcat:deploy
```

Remember to start tomcat before maven deployment.

If deployment is success , your application will be available at

```
http://tomcatserver:8080/myWebApp
```

Comment: How can we deploy application to multiple servers ?

Answer (score 1):

I Guess you are now executing the goal tomcat:deploy, Instead of that, try to run the goal **tomcat:redeploy** and also make sure that you have added tomcat-maven-plugin in pom.xml

Comment: **Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: The target server failed to respond**
actually the problem is with tomcat. Just  **start the tomcat manually** after that try to build.

Comment: maybe it's a problem with tomcat but can't figure out what: the deploymant over the webinterface works, maven can login to the manager and starts uploading

Comment: ya, did you try to start the tomcat manually and deploy after that??

Comment: tomcat is started manually, he is running all the time as a service

Comment: i just tried to debug the war-upload but the deploy-plugin seems to ignore the proxy settings